# TypeScript 1.5, reflection and decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

I was wondering if it was possible to use reflection, and more particularly class reflection concerning decorator, on property, on parameter or on method ?

Is this possible to use reflector to get the information used in the decorators ?

If it's possible, how can we do that ?
Else, why cant we do that ?

EDIT :

I have an application in which I use decorators, to inject data, from a serviceRegistry, to a decorator called @Inject.

In this application, I fill a simple service registry by hand, like :

```
serviceRegistry.push(MyClass1)
serviceRegistry.push(MyClass2)
...
serviceRegistry.push(MyClass100)
```

The aim is to be able to fill this service registry with classes that are decorated with @ToInject annotation, at runtime.

This will permit me to avoid to fill this registry by hand, and to automate this simply.

THanks for advance

Comment: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/04/30/announcing-typescript-1-5-beta.aspx) is an example. I didn't get it to work with PhantomJS 2 that just reported a syntax error.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? If you could provide an example, it would help to answer your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use reflection by importing the [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) package.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

Use it with TypeScript 1.5 and the compiler flag `emitDecoratorMetadata` set to true. Don't forget including a reference to `reflect-metadata.d.ts` as well.

You need to implement your own decorators:

```
// declare property decorator
function logType(target : any, key : string) {
  var t = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
  console.log(`${key} type: ${t.name}`);
}

class Demo{ 
  @logType // apply property decorator
  public attr1 : string;
}
```

It will log in console:

```
attr1 type: String
```

Another example:

```
// declare parameter decorator
function logParamTypes(target : any, key : string) {
  var types = Reflect.getMetadata("design:paramtypes", target, key);
  var s = types.map(a => a.name).join();
  console.log(`${key} param types: ${s}`);
}  

class Foo {}
interface IFoo {}

class Demo{ 
  @logParameters // apply parameter decorator
  doSomething(
    param1 : string,
    param2 : number,
    param3 : Foo,
    param4 : { test : string },
    param5 : IFoo,
    param6 : Function,
    param7 : (a : number) => void,
  ) : number { 
      return 1
  }
}
```

It will log in console:

```
doSomething param types: String, Number, Foo, Object, Object, Function, Function
```

Notice the that interfaces `IFoo` and object literal `{ test : string}` are serialized as `Object`. The serialization rules are:

- `number` serialized as `Number`
- `string` serialized as `String`
- `boolean` serialized as `Boolean`
- `any` serialized as `Object`
- `void` serializes as `undefined`
- `Array` serialized as `Array`
- If a `Tuple`, serialized as `Array`
- If a `class` serialized it as the class constructor
- If an `Enum` serialized it as `Number`
- If has at least one call signature, serialized as `Function`
- Otherwise serialized as `Object` (Including interfaces)

Interfaces and object literals may be serialize in the future via complex type serialization but this feature is not available at this time.

You can also get the return type of a function using:

```
Reflect.getMetadata("design:returntype", target, key);
```

If you need more info about decorators you can read : [Decorators & metadata reflection in TypeScript: From Novice to Expert](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on " Don't forget including a reference to reflect-metadata.d.ts as well."?

Comment: Reflect-metadata includes .d.ts files in the npm module. When I wrote this answer it was required to use a `/// <reference path="">` to the dts file. Today, if you are using TS >= 2.0 you don't need to do that.

Comment: Here is another example of Decorators usage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085883/how-to-create-a-simple-typescript-metadata-annotation

Answer (score 0):

I just released an enhanced version of the TypeScript compiler that provides full reflection capabilities:

- Classes/interfaces metadata at runtime
- Instantiate classes from metadata objects
- Retrieve metadata from class constructors

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/pcan/reflec-ts)

Comment: Can I ask you to please review [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Comment: TypeScript Community is asking for reflection capabilities since a long time. This is *the* answer to the question. No other library/compiler version can handle these requirements. Have a look at it. Furthermore, I said "I just released.." so it's clear that is a project I own.

Comment: I more meant that you should not be copying the exact same answer without detail to every question about TypeScript here without tailoring your answer and including proper examples.