# How to Create a Simple Typescript Metadata Annotation

Tags: json, serialization, typescript, angular, decorator

I have some fields that need to be formatted before sent to server-side.

So, I would like to serialize some fields of my typescript classes using custom serializers, something like that would be ideal:

```
export class Person {
    @serializeWith(MyDateSerializer)
    private date: Date;
}

post(url, value) {
    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringfy(value, (key, val) => {
       if (//value has serializeWith annotation) {
           return //serialize with custom serializer
       }
    }));
}
```

Anything close to this would be acceptable, any help is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My solution below is built on top of:

1. [TypeScript Decorators](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)
2. [Metadata spec (early stage/experimental)](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators)

### Prerequisites:

1. Enable Decorator and decorator metadata support in TypeScript in you `tsconfig.json` or on the command line:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5", // you have to target es5+
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
        // ....
    }
    // ...
}
```

2. Install `reflect-metadata` package

   npm install --save-dev `reflect-metadata`

### `serializerWith` Decorator (factory)

A decorator factory is something that takes one or many parameters and returns a decorator function that TypeScript uses in the generated JavaScript code.

I have chosen to directly pass the serialization function into my decorator factory and use the `reflect-metadata` implementation of the metdata spec to associate the serializer function with the property. I will later retrieve it and use it at run-time.

```
function serializeWith(serializer: (input: any) => string) : (target: any, propertyKey: string) => void {
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        // serialization here is the metadata key (something like a category)
        Reflect.defineMetadata("serialization", serializer, target, propertyKey);
    }
}
```

### Use

Given this serializer:

```
function MyDateSerializer(value : any) : string {
    console.log("MyDateSerializer called");
    return "dummy value";
}
```

We can then apply the decorator factory like this:

```
import "reflect-metadata"; // has to be imported before any decorator which uses it is applied

class Greeter {
    @serializeWith(MyDateSerializer)
    public greeting : string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
}
```

And we can get and use the serializer like this:

```
var greetingInstance = new Greeter("hi");

var serializerFunc : (input: any) => string = Reflect.getMetadata("serialization", greetingInstance, "greeting");

serializerFunc(greetingInstance.greeting);
```

### Sample

**main.ts**

```
import "reflect-metadata";

function serializeWith(serializer: (input: any) => string) : (target: any, propertyKey: string) => void {
    return function(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        console.log("serializeWith called: adding metadata");
        Reflect.defineMetadata("serialization", serializer, target, propertyKey);
    }
}


function MyDateSerializer(value : any) : string {
    console.log("MyDateSerializer called");
    return "bla";
}

class Greeter {
    @serializeWith(MyDateSerializer)
    public greeting : string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        console.log("Greeter constructor");
        this.greeting = message;
    }
}

var greetingInstance = new Greeter("hi");

var serializerFunc : (input: any) => string = Reflect.getMetadata("serialization", greetingInstance, "greeting");

var serializedValue = serializerFunc(greetingInstance.greeting);
console.log(serializedValue);
```

**Outputs**

```
c:\code\tmp\lll>node build\main.js
serializeWith called: adding metadata
Greeter constructor
MyDateSerializer called
bla
```